# How to create a new document using a .docx template in a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library, document-template

First of all, I am new to Sharepoint, and I am having trouble with some stuff.

I need to make a new word document in a document library using an existing .docx template. The new document should be created in a workflow and it should filled with the metadata of an list element.

Can anyone help me, give me a hint or a link to helpfull page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link can get you close to what you are trying to achieve. http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/sharepoint-designer-workflow-create-new-document-based-content-type.htm

This tutorial will get you there. 
https://prezi.com/rqsrihlo9fa7/sharepoint-lesson-35-sharepoint-list-creates-word-document/

Comment: thanks, i made it. now i have an another problem but i will make new post for this :D

Comment: Ok Luka... Happy to help and will look out for other post.